# Threading a Function in c# is not Working

Tags: c#, multithreading, gtk#, naudio

I have a problem with this code. The function is playing a music track, so it takes a while to finish executing.... However, even through it is threaded, it does not return untill it is done, holding up the rest of the program. Can I have the function exit so that the program continues but have the music keep on it's own thread. Any solutions are welcome.

```
using System;
using Gtk;
using NAudio;
using NAudio.Wave;
using System.Threading;

public class Trackbox {

    public static void Main() {
        Application.Init();

        //Create the Window
        Window myWin = new Window("Trackbox");
        myWin.SetIconFromFile("Assets//logo.png");
        myWin.Resize(200, 100);


        //Add the label to the form     
        //myWin.Add(myLabel);

        Button playButton = new Button("Play Sound");
        //This when playwav is called here, the rest of the application waits for it to finish playing

        playButton.Clicked += new EventHandler(playWav);
        myWin.Add(playButton);

        myWin.DeleteEvent += delegate { Application.Quit(); };
        //Show Everything     
        myWin.ShowAll();


        Application.Run();


    }

    private static void playWav(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        var soundFile = @"C:\sound.wav";
        using (var wfr = new WaveFileReader(soundFile))
        using (WaveChannel32 wc = new WaveChannel32(wfr) { PadWithZeroes = false })
        using (var audioOutput = new DirectSoundOut())
        {
            audioOutput.Init(wc);

            audioOutput.Play();

            while (audioOutput.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
            {
                Thread.Sleep(20);
            }

            audioOutput.Stop();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks for the help. If you have any ideas please post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your `playWav` is executed on the same thread as your UI is running on. That is why your UI is blocked.

You can start a new thread like this:

```
private volatile bool _QuitThread;

private void playWav(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    _QuitThread = false;
    Thread thread = new Thread(playWavThread);
    thread.Start();
}

// This method should be called when the music should stop. Perhapse when a button has been pressed.
private void StopTheMusic() 
{
    _QuitThread = true;
}

private void playWavThread()
{
    var soundFile = @"C:\sound.wav";
    using (var wfr = new WaveFileReader(soundFile))
    using (WaveChannel32 wc = new WaveChannel32(wfr) { PadWithZeroes = false })
    using (var audioOutput = new DirectSoundOut())
    {
        audioOutput.Init(wc);
        audioOutput.Play();
        while (!_QuitThread && audioOutput.PlaybackState != PlaybackState.Stopped)
        {
            Thread.Sleep(20);
        }
        audioOutput.Stop();
    }
}
```

**EDIT**

At request, I added code to quit the thread.

Comment: Thank you so much, this explains how thread work much better!

Comment: How Do I stop the Tread after the fact? Right now I can't kill it becuase the thread is in a static function.

Comment: It does not matter if the function is static or not. You should see a thread as a seperate "process" running next to the "main process". They run side by side and execute all kinds of code (statics, non statics, create instances, etc.). The best way to stop a thread is to set a flag. I will update my answer.

Comment: Thanks for the help, this is useful on pausing the music, but how do you kill the thread? I can't cause to to exit. I can get it to quit if I set the thread but even then I can't kill it in the program

Answer (score 0):

`DirectSoundOut` already creates its own playback thread. Get rid of the `Thread.Sleep` altogether which is blocking your thread and simply call `Play`. Subscribe to the `PlaybackStopped` event to detect  when playback has finished. The `audioOutput` would need to be a class member so you could `Dispose` it after playback had finished.

Comment: Could you give me a example, I get what you are saying but am not sure how implement this in my own code.